# $\sin(1/x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

> Show that  $$ f(x)=\sin\frac1x $$ is not uniformly continuous on
>   $(0,\frac\pi2]$.

It is looking easy to do this problem if it is asked for $(0, 1)$ but I am not getting for the given range of $(0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ . Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\delta > 0$. For $n$ big enough, 
$$0< y := \frac 1{\frac \pi 2 + (2n+1)\pi}< x := \frac 1{\frac \pi 2 + 2n\pi} <\delta$$ Now what is $f(x) - f(y)$?

Comment: How you selected x and y ?

Comment: there are close to 0, and I made sure that they took very distinct values.

Comment: SO if It has anything to with pi/2 ? because my domain says from (0, pi/2]

Comment: no it hasn't. in fact it is not uniformly continuous on any set $(0,r)$.

Comment: Now after I am calculating f(x) - f(y), then I think it would be less than 0. What to do next ?

Comment: what is this difference?

Comment: It would be [cos((2n+1)*pi) - cos(2n*pi)]

Comment: that is, if $n$ is an integer?

Comment: And then we can say that cosA - CosB = -2 $sqrt(sin(A+B)sin(A-B))$

Comment: square root can never be negative hence we can say that $f(x) - f(y)$ < 0

Comment: no! you can compute it on the spot. $\cos 2n\pi= 1$ (look at the damn circle!)

Comment: what should be this difference $f(x) - f(y)$ for not uniform continuous ?

Comment: @Pratik it tends to 0 as $|x-y|\to 0$. here for any $\delta$ as small as you like, you have $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x) - f(y)| = 2$.

Comment: Can you show me the steps to do this above problems Please. I am getting confused. PLease solve this so that I can getter better Idea for the problem

Comment: well, you have to prove that: $\forall \epsilon: \exists \delta : |x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)|<\epsilon$. Here it is false with $\epsilon = 2$, and $x,y$ such as defined in my answer. is it clear?

Comment: I got you now, Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 2):

If it is not uniformly continuous on $A$, it is not uniformly continuous on $B\supset A$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Try finding two sequences $\langle x_n\rangle$ and $\langle y_n \rangle $ such that $x_n-y_n\to 0$ and $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|>\epsilon_0(>0)$

**Note:** In $[a,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ for some $a>0$, $f(x)$ is continuous. That is, $f(x)$ is continuous on a closed and bounded interval and so is uniform continuous on the interval. The only possible point which is creating a problem is $x=0$. That's the reason why you need to choose $x_n-y_n\to 0$

Try $\langle x_n\rangle=\frac{1}{2n\pi}$ and $\langle y_n \rangle =\frac{1}{(4n+1)\pi /2} $, maybe.

Comment: What should be my $x_n$ and $y_n$ ? hOW TO SELECT THOSE

Comment: @Pratik: Edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

For $n\in N$ let $x_n=1/\pi n$ and $y_n=1/(\pi n+\pi /2).$
We have $0<|x_n-y_n|<1/n^2.$

Let $f(x)=\sin 1/x$ for $x\ne 0.$ We have $f(x_n)=0$ and $f(y_n)=\pm 1$ so $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=1.$

There cannot exist $d>0$ such that $\forall x,y\in (0,\pi/2]\;(|x-y|<d\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<1).$ Because for any $d>0$ there exists $n\in N$ with $1/n^2<d,$ so $|x_n-y_n|<d$ but $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=1.$

Draw a graph of $f(x)$ for $x\in (0,r]$ for some (any) $r>0.$